# Is there usage of such-as-clause?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses

A sentence from *the History of Western Philosophy* (by Russel):

> "Almost all the questions of most interest to speculative minds are such as science cannot answer"

I got the rough meaning of it, but failed to analyze the last part.

The whole sentence could be reduced to:

> "Questions are such as science cannot answer"

There seems to be a clause here.
But is there something like such-as-clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means ‘of a kind’. So, your clause would be, ‘Questions such as science cannot answer.’ Subject (Questions) and predicate (such as science cannot answer). You don’t need the ‘are’.  Synonymous with ‘Questions of a kind science cannot answer.’  See similar example from Oxford below, ‘an event such as we’ve shared.’

**such as**

PHRASE

•       1
For example.
‘wild flowers such as mountain pansy and wild thyme’

•               2
Of a kind that; like.
‘an event such as we've shared’

More example sentences

•       3
archaic Those who.
‘such as alter in a moment, win not credit in a month’

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I believe that Ressul made something unformal here.

Comment: NP, you can upvote it if it's useful!

Comment: I'm not reputationed enough to make a public upvote +_+